# How to listen to messages from a socket and print them to console in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, sockets, stream

Hey everyone so I'm really new to working sockets and TypeScript and I need to use both for a project I'm working on.

Basically, there is a server set up that handles events and each time an event occurs, a socket sends a message stating that the event occurred with some info about it. The socket continually sends these messages as a stream and I need to listen to those messages and simply print the message info to console.

I'd really appreciate any help you guys can offer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm honestly still figuring out how to simply form a connection to the server. I am only provided with a socketURL so the first step would be to connect to the URL

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that was your question, but this way you can create a socket server and output the message in the console.

```js
Server = 
net.createServer({
            allowHalfOpen : true
        })
.on('connection', (NetSocket) => {
    NetSocket
        .on('data', (data) => {
            var RemoteClient = NetSocket.remoteAddress + ':' + NetSocket.remotePort;
            console.log('message from ' + RemoteClient + ' // ' + data.toString()
        }
})
```